# How to set an Object as the value in JSON string Using Asp.Net Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am building a Jeopardy Web Api application to help prepare for .Net Technical Interviews.

I am using code first Entity Framework to create my database.

I am using Fiddler to test POSTS/GETs

I have 2 tables: Categories and JeopardyQuestion.

A question can have 1 category, and a category can have many questions.
The model setups are below.

```
public class JeopardyQuestion
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int  JeopardyQuestionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Question { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

}

public class Category
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }


    public virtual List<JeopardyQuestion> JeopardyQuestions { get; set; }

}
```

I was able to successfully POST 2 categories: Ado.net and Asp.net.  The 2 categories have empty list of questions.

My error comes when I try to POST a new Question and try to apply an existing category to it:

```
 {"Question" : "This framework allows developers to easily create web applications","Answer" : "What is Asp.Net", "Value" : "200", "Category" : "ASP.NET"}
```

Error

```
 {"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"jeopardyQuestion.Category":["Error converting value \"ASP.NET\" to type 'Jeopardy.Models.Category'. Path 'Category', line 1, position 152.","The Category field is required."]}}
```

My question is, how do I correctly set a Key/Value pair in JSON, when the Value needs to be an object? In this case, a Category Object?

More Specifically, how do I do

```
 "Category" : "ASP.NET"
```

Where ASP.NET is in the CategoryName column in the Category table in my database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a CategoryID field to your Question entity and send that. Let the actual Category be null. In addition you may consider creating DTO objects specifically for sending data to and from the service and have regular C# code in your controllers copy the data into entities. This helps when the shape of the data you want to expose is different from the shape of the data in the database or when there are parts of the data that should not be exposed.